# Multiple sed commands in a file

Tags: shell-script, sed

I want to save a .txt file to 2 separate .txt files using command placed in a .txt file. I can use

```
sed -e '1,20 w file1' -e '21,$ w file2' input.txt
```

But how would I plac e this command in a file called div so I could use it like this and get the same result

```
sed -f div input.txt
```

Comment: `echo $'1,20 w file1\n21,$ w file2' > div` and that's all you need.

Comment: This is a homework exercise to show me used commands. I keep getting the first 20 lines save in a file named  file1\n21,$ w file2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework question

Comment: @cuonglm Being homework does not make a question off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the two commands (your arguments to `-e`) into the text file.  So the contents of `div` should be:

```
1,20 w file1
21,$ w file2
```